# update security provider in Android

Tags: java, android, security, react-native

My application is developed using react native. I am kind of new to android and mobile development. Currently, I'm considering to add auto-update of security provider in Android as suggested in this link: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.

From this link, they suggest using SyncAdapter to update synchronously. But seem very complicated setting up a SyncAdapter(https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter), which includes:

- Create a SyncAdapter class
- Create Service class
- Create account metadata
  ...

Would like to know the advantage of using a `SyncAdapter` over directly calling `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded()` in Android `MainApplication`. Is it overkill in this scenario to use `SyncAdapter`.